# How do I simulate Bayes theorem in R to get a sense of uncertainty?

Tags: r, statistics, simulation, bayesian, sampling

Okay, so Bayes theorem is `p(A|B) = p(A) * P(B|A) * 1/p(B)`.

I want to simulate p(A|B) using all the uncertainty surrounding p(A), p(B|A) and p(B).

`rbeta` seems like a good choice.

data: imagine I just spent 20 days in a new location and have a sense of the daily weather.

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(4434)
sims = 1000 #let's simulate each of these proportions 1000 times
p(rain) = rbeta(sims,5,15) #it rained 5 times in the 20 days
p(overcast | rain) = rbeta(sims, 4,1) #of the 5 times it rained, it wasn't completely overcast 1x
p(overcast) = rbeta(sims, 10,10) #half of the days I was there were overcast
```

That should give me anything that I need to calculate `p(A|B)` or `p(rain | overcast)`. Let's calculate this and take a quick look:

```
data <- tibble(p_rain, p_overcast, p_overcast_rain) %>% 
  mutate(numerator = p_rain * p_overcast_rain,
         p_rain_overcast = numerator / p_overcast)


summary(data$p_rain_overcast)

table(data$p_rain_overcast > 1)
```

**the problem: I am getting results outside of the 0 to 1 bounds**
[image: Outside of the 0 to 1 bounds]

So, in 22 of the simulations the numerator > denominator, which would suggest the impossible: Both B and A happening is more likely than B happening. This is clearly a possible result with the simulation approach.

**The question: Now, assuming this approach isn't completely silly (is it?), I am curious about what do I do with values above 1 (or more generally outside of 0 to 1)?**

#if you're curious what I did#
I can see three options, but I am not sure about their validity or pitfalls:

**1. just make p_rain_overcast values > 1 = 1 **

```
data %>% 
  mutate(p_rain_overcast = ifelse(p_rain_overcast > 1, 
                                  1, 
                                  p_rain_overcast)) %>% 
  reframe(
    quantiles = c(0,.1,.25,.5,.75,.9,1),
    values = quantile(p_rain_overcast, c(0,.1,.25,.5,.75,.9,1)))
```

output:
[image: truncation results]

**2. I can resimulate until the numerator is less or equal to denominator **

```
SimNumerator <- function(limit, p_a, p_ba){
  
  numerator <- p_a * p_ba
  
  #something to put the values
  fillThis <- vector("numeric", length = length(numerator))
  
  for(i in 1:length(numerator)) {
    #one item at a time
    result <- numerator[i]
    
    #keep going until the numerator is less than or equal to denominator
    while(result > limit[i]){
      prior = rbeta(1,5,15) #it rained 5 times in the 20 days
      likelihood = rbeta(1, 4,1) #of the 5 times it rained, it wasn't completely overcast once
      result <- prior * likelihood
    }
    fillThis[i] <- result
  }
  return(fillThis)
}


new_numerator <- SimNumerator(p_a = p_rain,
                              p_ba = p_overcast_rain,
                              limit = p_overcast)


data %>% tibble(new_numerator) %>% 
  mutate(p_rain_overcast = new_numerator / p_overcast) %>%
  reframe(
    quantiles = c(0,.1,.25,.5,.75,.9,1),
    values = quantile(p_rain_overcast, c(0,.1,.25,.5,.75,.9,1)))
```

[image: resimulate]

**3. Is pretty much #2, but I resimulate until the denominator is greater than numerator**
This is just changing what gets resampled for rbeta.

#comparison#

[image: different results p(rain|overcast)]

The interpretations are similar (after all only 22 / 1000 values changed). The limiting approach creates a spike at 1. The resampling approach has a downside in that it is more likely for low p(overcast) or denominator values d OR high numerator values getting resampled, which might misrepresent some of the sampling distributions.

Comment: There's a lot in this question. My first observation from the first part is that you are making separate draws for your separate conditions and that's why you are getting probabilities more than 100%. For lots of good material on Bayes calcs using R I highly recommend the Statistical Rethinking book and videos from Richard McElreath: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLDcUM9US4XdPz-KxHM4XHt7uUVGWWVSus

Comment: Yes, as @JonSpring suggested, you shouldn't simulate the probabilities, you should just simulate the outcomes.  Pick 4 numbers for the 4 combinations of rain or not and overcast or not. If you really want to simulate the probabilities as well, then you'll have a 3 dimensional (since they add up to 1) set of results to display.  That's possible, but hard to interpret.

Comment: I voted to migrate this to Cross Validated since this would be tedious to answer without LaTeX. You seem to be confusing events and parameters. A and B here are your observational data (e.g., it rained 4 times out of 10 when it was overcast). If you want to perform inference on X = P(A|B), a simple Bayesian formulation would be P(X|A,B) = P(A,B|X)*P(X)/Integral(P(A,B|X)*P(X), X), where P(X) is your prior (i.e., *before* A and B are observed) information about the distribution of X. The binomial distribution is a natural choice for P(A,B|X), and the beta distribution for P(X) (cont.)

Comment: The beta distribution is conjugate to the binomial, so the posterior distribution of X would also be beta. As for the beta prior, if we are actually talking about rainfall, I would probably look at the type and quantity of vegetation when I arrived before choosing the parameters of that distribution. If I was considering a random location, I would pick relatively small parameter values, such as Beta(0.1, 2). Another alternative involves using observational data to choose the prior distribution, which is known as empirical Bayes.

Comment: Thank you all for working through this! Seems that I am making some substantial conceptual errors here. In my mind, however, I have a set of limited observations on p(A), p(B), P(B|A). The beta distribution should help me have a sense of the uncertainty surrounding my knowledge from my observations. I was thinking that I could propagate the uncertainty for each these parameters / proportions to get a sense of the uncertainty underlying p(A|B). I guess I could just do something like `stan_glm(rain ~ overcast, binomial())` to get that, but I guess I was just exploring another approach.

Comment: Do you think it would be better if I rephrased this question to make it about what I am doing conceptually wrong? The comments have been super useful for me. It seems that the best way for to simulate p(rain | overcast) would to use the beta distribution over my observations. I could use `rbeta(sims, rain & overcast, no rain & overcast)` to get a sense of uncertainty based on my observations (pbeta, dbeta, qbeta could also do the trick without simulating). Outcome VS.probabilities and trying to simulate something in multivariate space are particularly revealing frames for me.